# Multiple elements into 1 array cell?

Tags: c++, arrays

I must implement a program where i have an array with steady size and into each cell i must put one id,one counter ,and a pointer.My question is how i'm going to put more than 1 elements into 1 array cell?

Comment: An array of structures or classes?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO - a site for helping doing your homework, without the need to show some effort - NOT! show at least what you have tried so far and/or why/what isn't working... pls take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
struct Cell {
  Cell() : id(0), counter(0), pointer() {}
  int id, counter;
  std::unique_ptr<int> pointer;
};

Cell cells[100];
```

You can access the elements like this:

```
cells[0].id = 1;
++cells[0].counter;
cells[0].pointer.reset(new int(9));
```

Comment: i put this piece of code at .h file
struct entry
{
    
      int counter,page_id ;
 //   AvlTree *pointer;
 };
entry a[1000000];
and this piece if code at .cpp file

SortedArray::SortedArray() {
         a->page_id=0;
         a->counter=0;
         //       a->pointer=NULL;
}

I think it does the same thing with your code.right ?